# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

Tags: java, mysql

When I try to run this Test way:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class Demo1 {
    @Test
    public void run(){
        //create DataSource
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql:///spring_db");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("root");
        //create jdbcTemplate
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(driverManagerDataSource);
        System.out.println(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}
```

And I had put the mysql-connector-java dependency into my config.xml file,And this is all my dependencies:

[image]

While I get this error,how could I solve this problem?:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
at Demo1.run(Demo1.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:128)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MySQL Connector/J 8.0 JAR file, so the driver class name should be "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" and not "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".